# Remove indent with \cite

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, citing, cite-package

I don't want to have a space between my bracket and the default square bracket generate by the package `cite`. When I write:

```
(\cite{ref1,ref2})
```

the result is:

> ( [1], [2])

instead of

> ([1], [2])

How can I do to remove this space please?

Answer (score 14):

There are a couple of options that [`cite`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cite) package can override and in your case

```
\usepackage[nospace,noadjust]{cite}
```

should fix it. Other options can be found on page 4, Section **Customization**.